# virtualpc --> virtual-pc

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

**virtualpc**: 1 question

**virtual-pc**: 31 questions

There is no reason to have two tags. They mean the same thing.

Comment: The `virtualpc` question is http://superuser.com/questions/48968/how-do-i-convert-a-vhd-disk-image-to-work-with-vmware, if anyone with 500 rep wants to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Done. Edited it manually.